# Upload image from gallery with parameters and header using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload image but need to pass parameters and header as well, got help from google about parameters but not getting how to pass header also. Passing on the code below please guide.

Below is my code:

```
if (request.requestType == "Multipart")
    {
        var strToken : String = ""
        if let access_token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "auth_token"){
            let tokenValue = String(format: "Token %@", access_token);
            strToken = tokenValue
        }

        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": strToken,
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        ]

        let img = request.image 
        let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.2)!
        do{

            let strURL = try strCompleteURL.asURL()
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "image_path",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            for (key, value) in params {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
            }
        },
                         to:strURL)
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    if response.result.isSuccess {
                        print(response.result.value as Any)
                        if let data = response.data{
                            self.response.responseCode = response.response?.statusCode
                            self.processResult(data);
                        }
                    }
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):

                    print(encodingError)
            }
        }
        }
        catch{

        }
```

above code tries to upload image but not succeed because of missing header, please guide how to pass header and parameters as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I have used headers like this

```
func uploadImage( image:UIImage, url:String, _ successBlock:@escaping ( _ response: JSON )->Void , errorBlock: @escaping (_ error: NSError) -> Void ){

        let path =  baseUrl + url
        print(path)


        let headers = ["authorization": AppData().token]
        let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2)!

        let URL = try! URLRequest(url: path, method: .post, headers: headers)


        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "image",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "file")
for (key, value) in params {
                    multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
                }
        }, with: URL) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(response.result.value)
                    if let value = response.result.value {
                        let json = JSON(value)
                        successBlock(json)
                    }
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                errorBlock(encodingError as NSError)

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Problem with this line
let URL = try! URLRequest(url: path, method: .post, headers: headers)

Comment: what problem you have occur?

Comment: i am getting response from api is
    FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))
  ▿ failure : AFError
    ▿ responseSerializationFailed : ResponseSerializationFailureReason

Comment: may be its different problem. please check API response into postman

Comment: i see parameters are not passing in it

Comment: this error comes when some data is missing or wrong

Comment: pass parameter in multipart and check the response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155493/discussion-between-ios-singh-and-iphone-6).

Answer (score 0):

The Alamofire `.upload()` function has more parameters available than what you used. (This can be seen in the Alamofire.swift file in their pod folder)

```
public func upload(
multipartFormData: @escaping (MultipartFormData) -> Void,
usingThreshold encodingMemoryThreshold: UInt64 = SessionManager.multipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold,
to url: URLConvertible,
method: HTTPMethod = .post,
headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil,
encodingCompletion: ((SessionManager.MultipartFormDataEncodingResult) -> Void)?)
{
    return ...
}
```

In there you can see there is a parameter for *headers* that you have not made use of.

Without running the code myself and checking everything, this would be my best assumption of where your headers would go